# ¿Por qué cuando llamo a mi método FileStreamResult desde un ajax no se descarga un pdf?

Tags: ajax, asp.net

Estoy intentando llamar a mi función FileStream Result desde un ajax, la cuestión es que está llamando al método y lo hace todo dentro, he comprobado esto con un breakpoint, pero al final no está descargando el pdf que quiero. Antes se descargaba y lo llamaba desde así: "using (Html.BeginForm("EmisionAllLabel", "WareHouseReceipt", FormMethod.Post))". Pero ahora necesito hacerlo desde un ajax pero no me funciona. Tal vez sea porque se me escapa algo pero no tengo mucha experiencia con ajax respecto a esto y no consigo identificar el problema. Agradezco sus comentarios. Adjunto los códigos utilizados:

```
$('#btnValidarEmision').on("click", function () {

    let emisionguia = $('#guiaAerea').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/WareHouseReceipt/" + "EmisionEtiqueta",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "guiaAerea": emisionguia },
        success: function (saved) {

        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

FileStreamResult

```
public FileStreamResult EmisionEtiqueta(string guiaAerea)
{

    IList<ICriterion> criterionlist = new List<ICriterion>();
    criterionlist.Add(Expression.Eq("Econtainer", true));
    criterionlist.Add(Expression.Eq("StatusId", 1));
    criterionlist.Add(Expression.Eq("Emision", false));
    IList<VwWareHouseReceipt> etiquetas = vwWarehouseReceiptDao.findByCriteria(criterionlist);


    //mem buffer
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();



    //the document
    Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(float.Parse("289.50"), 370, 0, 0));

    BaseFont bf2 = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

    BaseFont helveticanormal = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, true);
    BaseFont helveticanegrita = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, true);

    //create the fonts
    BaseFont timesNormal = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN,
                                               BaseFont.CP1252,
                                               BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

    Font fontSmall = new Font(timesNormal, 7, Font.NORMAL);

    Font fontNormal = new Font(timesNormal, 9, Font.NORMAL);

    Font fontH1 = new Font(timesNormal, 16, Font.NORMAL);

    //the writer
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);//fs);

    // step 3: we open the document
    document.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < etiquetas.Count; i++) { 
    

    }
    document.Close();

    //close the document
    // document.PageSize = PageSize.HALFLETTER;
    //document.PageSize = PageSize.

    //prepare output stream\
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=EtiquetasEmisionEcont" + guiaAerea + ".pdf");
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return new FileStreamResult(Response.OutputStream, "application/pdf");
```

Note:  He eliminado el "for" para que no haya demasiado texto.

Answer (score 0):

la manera correcta de llamar un FileStreamResult desde el front es

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.target = "_blank";
a.href = host() + "/WareHouseReceipt/EmisionEtiqueta/?guiaAerea=" + emisionguia;
a.click();
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos.